# ActionBarSherlock menu button triggers onOptionsItemSelected in another fragment

Tags: menu, actionbarsherlock

I have two menu buttons in separate fragments as shown in the codes below. Strangely, when I press the button ("Home") in the first fragment (and of course, the button in the second fragment), it fires the onOptionsItemSelected in the 2nd fragment.

If I have onOptionsItemsSelected in both fragments, the one in the first fragment is fired for the buttons in both fragments, and the menu id appears as 1 for both buttons.

What can I do to make different buttons do different things? (by firing different events or by generating different menu id's.)

```
 public static class MenuFragment extends SherlockFragment {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setHasOptionsMenu(true);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
     menu.add("Home").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
 }
 }

 /**
  * Second fragment with a menu.
  */
 public static class Menu2Fragment extends SherlockFragment {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setHasOptionsMenu(true);
     }

 @Override
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
     menu.add("Filter").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) // This gets fired when Menu 1 is selected
 {
     int id = item.getItemId();
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Option " + id+ " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```